# commands to stop & start nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx

I am developing **Rails v2.3.2** app. on a **Ubuntu** machine.

Now, I would like to have two rake tasks to **stop** and **start** **Nginx** respectively , what are the commands for this?

```
  task :start_nginx do
     puts "stop Nginx..."
     system '...' #What is the command to stop Nginx?
  end

  task :stop_nginx do
     puts "stop Nginx..."
     system '...' #What is the command to start Nginx?
  end
```

Answer (score 6):

If you just installed the regular nginx package on Ubuntu, you already have a start script like:

```
/etc/init.d/nginx (start|stop)
```

If you don't have that, please have a look [into the documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/GettingStarted#Running_Nginx):

> Start the server by running /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx as root.

You stop the server by executing

```
kill `cat /var/run/nginx.pid`
```

Answer (score 4):

The polically-correct way in Ubuntu is to use service instead of init.d

```
sudo service nginx stop
sudo service nginx start
sudo service nginx restart
```

[Explanation on the difference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2075/whats-the-difference-between-service-and-etc-init-d)

Answer (score 2):

It's system dependent.

If you're using upstart, the commands would be:

```
start nginx
stop nginx
```

Otherwise it may be one of:

```
/etc/init.d/nginx start
/etc/init.d/nginx stop

/etc/rc.d/nginx start
/etc/rc.d/nginx stop
```

Or even maybe:

```
nginx
killall -9 nginx
```

Comment: Why you have two starts and stops? are they all need to be run? or either one is ok?

Comment: either one depending on your system, for example debian uses `/etc/init.d`, but arch uses `/etc/rc.d`

Answer (score 2):

On debian/ubuntu

```
/etc/init.d/nginx (start|stop|reload)
```

On centOS/RHEL

```
service nginx (start|stop|reload)
```

You must be logged in as root.